# How to Encrypt/decrypt data in a Waves Keeper Web App?

Tags: wavesplatform

currently developing a new feature on my Web App i'm having a question:

I encrypted some data because i dont want it public in the blockchain but i  have some concern about this, ideally the encrypt/decrypt password should be the privatekey of the keeper connected user but since we don't have access to this info in Waves Keeper, what would be the best practice ?

How can we encrypt/decrypt data in a decentralized manner with Waves Keeper?

im currently using a password predefined by me as an environment variable on the server side but this is far from ideal and definitelly centralized aside of having several downside.

Of course there is few backup options like:

1) Simply avoid put any non public data in the blockchain

2) Add an encrypt/decrypt field in the App requiring user to enter his password everytime

Both would work but are just getting around the problem and not ideal, would like to know if there is any good solution first :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods in Waves Keeper API to encrypt/decrypt data. You can find details on the github.
https://github.com/wavesplatform/waveskeeper

Comment: Hi Inal and thanks a lot for your answer. 

I have to admit that i never saw these 2 methods before but if they require a secret specific to the app, its the same as just using a secret predefined on the server side no?

Comment: Ok, since the secret is not mandatory, my conclusion would be that you put a secret related to your app only if you don't want the info to be decryptable on a 3rd party app, if not, waveskeeper is the default secret and it can be decrypted anywhere as long as connected with the correct account, im correct?